Android ColorMatrix Alpha Threshold and Mask
I am trying to write some code that modifies the alpha value in every pixel in a bitmap such that if the pixels alpha is < threshold the alpha will be set to 0f. I am starting by creating a bitmap which consists of 2 nearby circles which are drawn with a radial gradient shader, going from fully opaque to transparent. This means the edges of the 2 circles are fuzzy and transparent and that the fuzzy parts of the circles overlap.
First
I am then applying a threshold with a ColorMatrix that is shifting all the alpha values by a fairly large amount (in this case, about -153) which effectively "pulls" back the fuzzy edges of the overlapping circles and makes them look like they are a conjoined blob.
Here is the ColorMatrix I am using to achieve that:
  val colorMatrix = ColorMatrix(
            floatArrayOf(
                1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, // Red
                0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, // Green
                0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, // Blue
                0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, -153f // Alpha channel 
            )
        )

Which results in this:
Second
Next I want to finally make all the pixels that remain within this newly defined area be fully opaque (i.e. remove  all the transparency in any pixels that are not fully transparent).
I am struggling however to achieve this last part using a ColorMatrix. If I add further matrix transforms on the first ColorMatrix to attempt to achieve this second goal, it breaks the output that I am desiring which is achieved with the first ColorMatrix alone.
I am thinking maybe I need to render the image (which is now in a canvas) back to a different bitmap, and then clear the canvas and repaint this new bitmap into the canvas with a new ColorMatrix. This works, but it seems convoluted...
Convoluted
Does anyone have any idea how to proceed? I need this thing to be hyper optimal as ultimately it's going to need to run in real time for animations.
I have written an OpenGL ES2 shader that achieves a similar thing, but ultimately decided it was going to be too complex for later requirements to proceed down that route, so I don't want any advice telling me to go the shader route.

I'm not sure what you mean by "convoluted", but have you tried to setAntiAlias(true) before drawing the circles?

convoluted means "overly complex". I ended up using RenderNode so I no longer need help with this.
